# html shortcut on smartphones

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I wonder if there is any chance, either javascript or some code, to know if the user is visiting the page on the mobile device directly from the navigator or from a shortcut from the home screen? I need to know this so show a message to invite the user to create a shortcut and then use the web page in the app like mode.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3) notes how you can tell for iOS; you have to set a meta tag to turn on standalone mode and then check `window.navigator.standalone`.

However, as far as I can tell, there is no equivalent for Android's built-in browser or for Chrome on Android. See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) for mobile Chrome: "How can I detect if the app is running as an installed app?
You can’t, directly." And also: "Do not prompt the user to add your app to the homescreen. There is no way to detect if the app is running installed or not."